# is there a script to find the app permisisons?

Tags: azure-powershell

can you help to find the list of Azure applications where Application permission named Mail.* (it could be any permission Mail.Read/Mail.ReadWrite/Mail.Send/or any other)?
should use Powershell for this activity.

Note : Certain applications can have Delegated Mail.* permission (which we do not want).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for permissions assigned to Service Principals...

```
$ManagedIDs = Get-MgServicePrincipal -All
$ManagedIDs.Count
$AllAppRoles = @()
ForEach ($ManagedID in $ManagedIDs) {
    $ManagedIDRoles = Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $ManagedID.Id
    $AssignedRoles = @()
    ForEach ($Role in $ManagedIDRoles) {
        $AssignedRoles += (Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($Role.ResourceDisplayName)'").AppRoles | 
            Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $Role.AppRoleId} | Select-Object @{N="Name";E={$Role.PrincipalDisplayName}}, @{N="Resource";E={$Role.ResourceDisplayName}}, Value, DisplayName, Description, ID
    } 
    $AllAppRoles += $AssignedRoles
}
$AllAppRoles.count
$AllAppRoles | Group-Object Value | Sort-Object Count -Descending | Select-Object Count, Name
$AllAppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -like "Mail.*"} | Format-Table
```